# Sequelize associations: include entity in JSON response

Tags: mysql, json, node.js, sequelize.js

I have three tables: **videoclips**, **playlists** and **videoclipPlaylistMap**.

- Videoclips table has an int *id* as the primary key and a *videoId* as a string.
- VideoclipPlaylist map has a *playlistId* as a foreign key pointing to the id from playlists table and a *videoclipId* as a foreign key which points to ***videoId*** from videoclips table.

I want to return a JSON containing all playlists and for each playlist an array of the containted videoclips.

I can't figure out how to do the sequelize associations in order to achieve that.

```
let Videoclip = sequelize.define('videoclip',{
    title: Sequelize.STRING,
    videoId: Sequelize.STRING,
    thumbnail: Sequelize.STRING,
    channelTitle: Sequelize.STRING,
    duration: Sequelize.DOUBLE,
    viewCount: Sequelize.INTEGER
});

let Playlist = sequelize.define('playlist', {
    name: Sequelize.STRING,
    userId: Sequelize.INTEGER,
    tagList: Sequelize.STRING
});

let VideoclipPlaylistMap = sequelize.define('videoclipPlaylistMap', {
    videoclipId: Sequelize.STRING,
    playlistId: Sequelize.INTEGER
});

User.hasMany(Playlist, {foreignKey: 'userId'});
Playlist.belongsTo(User, {foreignKey: 'userId'});
Playlist.hasMany(VideoclipPlaylistMap, {foreignKey: 'playlistId'});
VideoclipPlaylistMap.belongsTo(Videoclip, {foreignKey: 'videoclipId'});
```

As it is now it's executing this join:

```
LEFT OUTER JOIN `videoclips` AS `videoclipPlaylistMaps.videoclip` ON `videoclipPlaylistMaps`.`videoclipId` = `videoclipPlaylistMaps.videoclip`.`id`
```

And instead of that `videoclipPlaylistMaps.videoclip`.`id` it should go to `videoclipPlaylistMaps.videoclip`.`videoId`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to tell Sequelize to use the videoId field as the target key for the relationship.  By default, in a belongsTo association, the model's primary key is used as the target key.  You need to use the targetKey option in the association.

```
    VideoclipPlaylistMap.belongsTo(Videoclip, { foreignKey: 'videoclipId', targetKey: 'videoId' });
```

http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/associations.html#target-keys